# Woocommerce checkout payment mismatch error Phonepe gateway partial payment error

Tags: mismatch, phonepe

We are using partical cod advance plugin this plugin help us to collect advance payment for cod order maybe phonepe gateway not allow this. Please check with the backend and allow us also we are using same plugin with our another website and payment gateway is cashfree and razorpay this plugin is working fine my another website.

Once customer select cod and pay advance amount phonepe gateway show payment successful and page not going thanks order page it show payment mismatch.

Wordpress Plugin url https://wordpress.org/plugins/partial-cod-payment-gateway-restrictions-fees/

Once customer select cod and pay advance amount phonepe gateway show payment successful and page not going thanks order page it show payment mismatch.

Wordpress Plugin url https://wordpress.org/plugins/partial-cod-payment-gateway-restrictions-fees/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: did you tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-phonepe/??